# Bash if statement expression evaluates to FALSE but $? is 0, why?

Tags: bash, exit-code, return-code

The example below echoes `1`, as expected:

```
test -f /usr/bin
echo "$?" #1
```

Why does the following example echo `0`?

```
if [[ -f /usr/bin ]]; then
    echo "Inside if statement" # This line is never executed    
fi
echo "$?" #0
```

I know that the `$?`evaluates to the returned value of the last executed command. In my understanding, the last executed command is `test`, that is implicitly called by the `if` statement, since the condition evaluates to false it should return `1`, but when I execute it, it returns `0`. Can anybody explain why the behavior is different than when `test` is executed directly (like in the first example)?

Comment: Think about it: If this _weren't_ the behavior, then you'd have scripts reporting errors when all you had were conditionals branching false. (Remember, the default exit status is `$?` -- that of the prior command -- so everyone would need to put explicit `true` or `exit 0` commands in their scripts to override exit status left over from conditionals; that would be a mess).

Comment: (The other thing, though... note [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) -- Stack Overflow is focused narrowly on _practical_ questions -- ones whose answers will change how you go about the practice of software development; since you already know what actual behavior is and how to write code that works correctly in light of that behavior, I'm not sure I see an on-topic question)

Comment: See also `"Compound Commands"` in `man 1 bash` for an additional way to use the logic.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not think from that perspective. Thanks for your observation. I had a wrong understanding of `$?` behavior. I thought the executed commands in the `if` condition could update the value of `$?`. Now I see the logic behind it. If no branch of the `if` statement is executed, then the value of `$?` is updated to `0`. Or we could formulate it in a better way: __Conditions inside control flow statements do not update the value of `$?`__, only commands in the body of the control flow statements update the value of `$?`. If no branch is executed then the value of `$?` is `0`.

Comment: Mostly accurate, but the summary isn't quite universally true: During an `else` branch `$?` is left to the specific value the conditional left it at, so you can then distinguish between specific error codes _within the `else`_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man bash`:

> - if *list*; then *list*; [ elif *list*; then *list*; ] ... [ else *list*; ] fi
>
>   The `if` *list* is executed.  If its exit status is zero, the `then` *list* is  executed.   Otherwise,  each  `elif` *list*  is executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding `then` *list* is executed and the
>   command completes.  Otherwise, the `else` *list* is executed, if present.  The exit status is the exit  status
>   of the last command executed, **or zero if no condition tested true**.

Comment: Insofar as bash is following the POSIX.2 standard in this behavior, it might be worth referring back there as well. After all, the reason _why_ bash is defined the way the man page above specifies is because it wouldn't be POSIX-compliant otherwise.

Comment: (there's a larger question about why POSIX is written the way it is, with a good answer, but that's getting even further off-topic than the question already is)